# How to get social media links from Google Knowledge

Tags: facebook, instagram, social-media, google-knowledge-graph

I'm working on a project that requires me to collect celebrities followers number (from instagram or facebook).

To get that number, i have to get

1. celebrities instagram link
2. celebrities facebook link
3. send a request to instagram or facebook API to get their followers number

I have been researching for google knowledge API for celebrities instagram and facebook link. but what I get from it isn't satisfying.
For example, I put a request on google Knowledge,

```
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=Ariana+Grande&limit=1&indent=1&key={API-CODE}
```

and the result is

> {"@context": {
> "@vocab": "schema.org/",
> "goog": "schema.googleapis.com/",
> "EntitySearchResult": "goog:EntitySearchResult",
> "detailedDescription": "goog:detailedDescription",
> "resultScore": "goog:resultScore",
> "kg": "g.co/kg"
> },
> "@type": "ItemList",
> "itemListElement": [
> {
> "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
> "result": {
> "@id": "kg:/m/09gkdy4",
> "name": "Ariana Grande",
> "@type": [
> "Thing",
> "Person"
> ],
> "description": "Singer",
> "image": {
> "contentUrl": "t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS3KH3ae6ChLCPLguyQXbLbEXDTNMZ1Sb2LsMx6Vr-pjeuHg5AZ",
> "url": "da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariana_Grande",
> "license": "creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0"
> },
> "detailedDescription": {
> "articleBody": "Ariana Grande-Butera, known professionally as Ariana Grande, is an American singer and actress. She began her career in the Broadway musical 13, before landing the role of Cat Valentine on the Nickelodeon television series Victorious in 2009. ",
> "url": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariana_Grande",
> "license": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License"
> },
> "url": "www.arianagrande.com"
> },
> "resultScore": 802.862244
> }
> ]
> }

There's no information regarding her instagram or facebook link from the result, but if we search manually on google, it shows her instagram and facebook link on search result.

My question are:

1. Any way to get those link from Google knowledge?
2. Or any easier way to get follower number from celebrities beside my way? (jugling from 2-3 different APIs)

Comment: Looking for the answer as well. You asked this a while back, did you get to any answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wikidata.org. There are steps:

1. Search `https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=Ariana+Grande&language=en&format=json`

   {"searchinfo":{"search":"Ariana Grande"},"search":[{"id":"Q151892","concepturi":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q151892","url":"//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q151892","title":"Q151892","pageid":153289,"label":"Ariana Grande","description":"American actress, singer, composer and dancer","match":{"type":"label","language":"en","text":"Ariana Grande"}}],"success":1}
2. Get id `Q151892` from the response and get the entity `https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q151892&format=json&props=claims`

There is a big response. You need the value `arianagrande` of claim `P2003` from a list of claims. It refers to Instagram username (`P2013` for Facebook)

3. Get public info from `https://www.instagram.com/arianagrande/?__a=1`

   ```
   user:
   follows:
       count
   followed_by:
       count
   media:
       count
   ```

Comment: I will save this for letter, since I been moved to another project, but someday I will back to this. thanks for you responso tho.